# Do we use single colon in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

For ex, I have a query in postgreSQL such that "product_version=:productVersion".
It's giving me a syntax error.

Comment: Programming language/tools? What runs the SQL? What's the *exact text* of the error message? PostgreSQL version? There's a whole lot missing here.

Comment: Looks like a named parameter placeholder for which ever language or database framework you are using.

Answer (score 2):

It's giving you a syntax error because it makes no sense as SQL, and is invalid syntax.

(Please always show the *exact text* of error messages*)

Since inserting the string literal `:productVersion` doesn't make much sense, e.g.

```
product_version=':productVersion'
```

you might be using the `psql` command line client and trying to substitute a client variable. If so, you need to use a quoted substitution, e.g.:

```
product_version=:'productVersion'
```

but this *only works* for `psql`. Not Rails and the Pg gem, not JDBC, not PHP, not psycopg2, nothing but `psql`.

If that's not what you meant, then either you are using a programming language with placement parameters and using the wrong parameter syntax for your language, or you are attempting to use the `psql` command line client's variable substitution and aren't using `psql`. Impossible to guess what you mean unless you specify the language/tools used.

Look up the placement parameter syntax for your programming language and database driver. Make sure you're using the right one.