# Postgresql INTERSECT randomly not working

Tags: postgresql

I've got a problem with the syntax of a SQL query. It works sometimes and sometimes not. It's defenitly a problem with the query.
An error at or near "INTERSECTSELECT".
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.id,
                        s.title,
                        s.question,
                        s.comments,
                        s.start_date,
                        s.end_date,
                        s.motivation,
                        s.goals,
                        s.method,
                        s.type,
                        s.channel,
                        s.rhythm,
                        s.sample
                    FROM study s
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN study_customer_information sci
                    ON sci.study_id = s.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_information ci
                    ON ci.id = sci.customer_information_id
                    WHERE s.is_active = :isActive
                    AND
                    s.language = :language AND s.id IN (SELECT sci.study_id
                    FROM study_customer_information sci
                    INNER JOIN customer_information ci
                    ON ci.id = sci.customer_information_id
                    WHERE ci.name_de in (:customer_informations)
                    GROUP BY sci.study_id
                    HAVING COUNT(sci.study_id) = :number_customer_informations INTERSECT SELECT st.study_id
                    FROM study_touchpoint st
                    INNER JOIN touchpoint tp ON tp.id = st.touchpoint_id
                    INNER JOIN subject_area sa ON sa.id = tp.subject_area_id
                    WHERE sa.name_DE = :subject_areas_0 INTERSECT SELECT st.study_id
                    FROM study_touchpoint st
                    INNER JOIN touchpoint tp ON tp.id = st.touchpoint_id
                    INNER JOIN touch_point_type tpt ON tpt.id = tp.touch_point_type_id
                    WHERE tpt.name_DE = :touchpoint_types_0 INTERSECT SELECT sth.study_id
                    FROM study_theme sth
                    INNER JOIN theme th
                    ON th.id = sth.theme_id
                    WHERE th.name_de in (:themes)
                    GROUP BY sth.study_id
                    HAVING COUNT(sth.study_id) = :number_themes) ORDER BY s.title
```

Comment: hopefully [this answer help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32562498).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: where did you run this?

Comment: Through Java. It's really weird. I've looked at the syntax and its seems to be correct.

Comment: did it run for once in java?

Comment: It did work. It's a query with subqueries. So it adds those subqueries which has the intersect in it. It adds the subquery when you select something on the website. Some combination do work and other not. Those which do not work do work with other combinations.

Comment: first thing first, have a [tour] and read [mcve]. you should notice that you withheld some important information: 1) it ran through java (you didnt say what is the driver, is it `jdbc`?), 2) your code dynamically adds subquery, 3) the example which works and which doesnt. apart from those points, you should aware that database engines may have limits on the number of table, joins, intersect, and memory used in a single query. you should check the database log if possible should the query trigger warnings. also, try to breakdown your query, everything is in a single indentation (yikes)

Comment: oh right, i should also say, if you read the link i provided earlier, `jdbc` doesnt support `:some-param-name` thing. i do curious what black magic you use to pass the query into `psql`. it is possible that your magic truncated the query due to some limitations and triggers the syntax error.

Comment: I think your code doesn't add the space between INTERSECT and SELECT, hence you get a strange token INTERSECTSELECT

Comment: Yeah, its jdbc.

Comment: @fdreger the query I posted above does have a space between INTERSECT and SELECT. I printed the query into the console.

Comment: The error message says it does not: 'An error at or near "INTERSECTSELECT".'